# How can I count and reduce the occurence of a value in an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => test
            [...]  => ...
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => wine
            [...]  => ...

        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => wine
            [...]  => ...
        )

)
```

Now, what I want to achieve is something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => test
            [occurrence] => 1
            [...]  => ...
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => wine
            [occurence] => 2
            [...]  => ...
        )

)
```

In short, I want to deduplicate the items based on the unique `name` key, and I want to add a counter `occurrence` to the result which tells me how often each item occurred. The items have many more keys, which should be preserved (keeping the values of the first occurrence is fine).

Comment: On what key you count as duplicate (only on name key) and also what id will this resulting array element has?

Comment: Sorry, I have little patience scrolling back and forth to spot the difference in your arrays. A simplified sample would be very welcome. However, in general, to deduplicate arrays, use the id as a key: `$deduped[$item['name']] = $item`. Just loop over all items, setting the key in a new array, which easily lets you check whether a value already exists or not and increment a counter appropriately.

Comment: @Standej the key is "name" and it would be fine to just keep the first occurrence of the duplicated items.

Comment: I assume this is the result of a database query. In that case it might be a better idea to amend the query to generate the data in the format you actually require rather than doing a post query fiddle on the results

Comment: I've generalised the question and posted a simple answer below. I hope this can be used as canonical reference in the future, since this is asked literally **all the time.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $item) {
    if (!isset($result[$item['name']])) {
        $result[$item['name']] = $item;
        $result[$item['name']]['occurrence'] = 1;
    } else {
        $result[$item['name']]['occurrence']++;
    }
}
```

Simply use the fact that array keys are unique, and you'll have your data deduplicated in a single loop iteration.

Comment: Thank you sir, much appreciated.