# How to create an array based upon two value of an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with multiple keys,

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [type] => ab_micro_list
            [title] => Testing List
            [user_id] => 70318
            [micro_list_id] => 390
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [type] => ab_micro_list
            [title] => Testing List
            [user_id] => 70319
            [micro_list_id] => 390
        )

)
```

based upon this array I need to create array like this

```
Array
    (
        ['Testing List'] => Array
            (
                ['users'] => Array
                         (
                               [0] => 70318
                               [1] => 70319
                         )

            )
    )
```

Is there any way to achieve this. If someone has any suggestions, Please share.

Comment: Close enough that it should help you along: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34086735/476

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I count and reduce the occurence of a value in an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34086103/how-can-i-count-and-reduce-the-occurence-of-a-value-in-an-array)

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
    $arr = array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [type] => ab_micro_list
                [title] => Testing List
                [user_id] => 70318
                [micro_list_id] => 390
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [type] => ab_micro_list
                [title] => Testing List
                [user_id] => 70319
                [micro_list_id] => 390
            )

    );
    $finalArr = array();
    foreach($arr as $key=>$value){

       $finalArr[$value->title]['users'][] = $value->user_id;

    }
```

Comment: Sorry i just missed the user_id